Tag color: blue or gray
Is there a change in the appearance of tags in MSE?? It used to be blue in color but now it is gray. 
What is happening in Mathstackexchange?

See here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395062/seeking-feedback-on-tag-colors-update?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top The black and grey tag coloring seems to be the default but some sites have modified this to better fit their sites' colors. For example, Physics StackExchange changed from the default to their signature light green https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Today's post on [meta.se]: All tag labels suddenly appear in bold font

Man this sitewide change is rough. I'm not sure why they thought this was a good idea.

@CameronWilliams same...the blue was more attractive imo

The old one looks a lot better.

I really hope the colors of tags are changed to be blue again.

Even if it is decided to revert to blue, I hope that the text is kept bold and is not reverted to lightweight.

Blue. ${}{}{}{}{}$

@Etemon hehe I know the trick....{} Is a very good feature
